# javascript doesn't work in content page that use masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use a kind of javascript,when i use it in a page without master page it works properly but when i use it in content page that use master page it doesn't work what should  i do for this problem?

i don't use any code in masterpage for javascript is it necesssary ?

```
//Page1 without MasterPage
....
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () 
        {
            $.mask.definitions['~'] = "[+-]";
            $("#date").mask("99/99/9999"); //Date
            $("input").blur(function () 
            {
                $("#info").html("Unmasked value: " + $(this).mask());
            }).dblclick(function () {
                $(this).unmask();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
....
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    date :  <asp:TextBox ID="date"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
.....

//page2 with MasterPage
...
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () 
        {
            $.mask.definitions['~'] = "[+-]";
            $("#date").mask("99/99/9999"); //Date
            $("input").blur(function () 
            {
                $("#info").html("Unmasked value: " + $(this).mask());
            }).dblclick(function () {
                $(this).unmask();
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
....
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
     date : <asp:TextBox ID="date"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>


//Master Page
...
<head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net when a UserControl is placed in a container the unique IDs of its contained controls are recalculated to avoid problems with multiple controls of the same type. this is true even for pages inside master pages.

to retrieve the correct unique ID of the controls in your page you need to write something like this

```
$("#<%= date.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
```

the `<%= ... %>` will be evaluated at runtime and replaced with the correct id (ClientID is a property of asp.net control which holds the unique id of the control to be rendered)

Comment: just noticed, you inverted the loading order of your javascript.
`jquery.maskedinput.js` must be loaded *after* `jquery-1.4.4.min.js`

Comment: Great spot @Crisim  :-)  I would suggest you add an update to your answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

The ID of the rendered control is different from the ID you call it.

If you look at the HTML source that is sent to the browser, your `date` control will actually be called something like `ct100_date`.

So find the actual rendered ID and change `$("#date")` to something like `$("#ct100_date")`.

For example, it you view the source and find your textbox control in the rendered HTML it will look something like:

```
<input type="text" id="ct100_date" />
```

Javascript \ jQuery running on the browser will only find the control if you search for the *exact* `id` of the control. So take the `id` of the control in the HTML and seach for it with (*for example*) `$("#ct100_date")`

Comment: you mean now i change `date` to `ct100_date` or it's example? i change it but doesn't work,how should i find new ID ?

Comment: it's just an example, @Sajjjjjjad. Will update answer, give me a few minutes

Comment: i use firefox and when i run my page i right click on page and click on view page source and see the id of textbox is `ContentPlaceHolder1_date` and use this id instead of `date` but doesn't work

Comment: I find that surprising. So `$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_date")` doesn't find anything? If the javascript is actually in your  .aspx page, then I would recommend using Crisim's method of using `$("#<%=date.ClientID%>")`

Comment: sorry,i upload website here,if you can see it : http://www.mediafire.com/?3ybxxy9ukl39shj

Comment: In that case, there must be something else going on that we're not aware of, because both myself and Crisim are telling you the correct procedure. Check to see if the command is return the object, using [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com) to step through the javascript. Don't think there is anything else we can doi